# check if movieclip track has segment

Tags: python, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I'd like to remove all tracks in a movieclip that don't have any segment.
Since there's no such operator, I'd like to do it in python but I can't find a way to check if a track has a segment.

I've tried things like `tracks['some-track'].has_bundle` or `average_error` but these don't certify it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good check:

```
track = bpy.data.movieclips['some_clip'].tracking.tracks['some_track']
len(track.markers) <= 3
```

As I understand it, each track has one marker per tracked frame and for some reason, some tracks with no segment can still have up to 3 markers.

There might be a better solution but so far I haven't had an issue with that.